# Problemas con conexión VPN UBUNTU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, vpn, ping

tengo un problema con el FORTICLIENT en Ubuntu. Logro conectarme a la VPN y luego uso REMMINA para conectarme a la maquina REMOTA que tiene WINDOWS. Abro una terminal arrojo un ping a la IP recibe datos. Hasta acá todo funciona excelente pero luego de un tiempo se desconecta la VPN y deja de recibir datos.
Instale OpenFortiGui y KRDC logro conectarme a la VPN pero también se desconecta al rato.
Cuando uso el FORTICLIENT en WINDOWS se conecta sin problema.

¿Que puede estar sucediendo?

Comment: Mirar los logs del cliente y revisar.

Comment: lo acabo de revisar y no hay registro de lo q paso.  solo muestra que esta conectado nada mas

Comment: Tienes que revisar los logs en tu máquina. No sabemos ni la versión de Ubuntu siquiera, así que es difícil dar más ideas. El problema tiene toda la pinta de ser de configuración; puede que el servidor espere algún keepalive que no estás enviando o que falte configurar algo para mantener viva la sesión. Estamos más a oscuras que tú y nos tienes adivinando. Si no añades más info, la pregunta fijo termina cerrada porque no hay forma de ayudarte.

Answer (score -1):

Tengo el mismo problema y no es configuración, lo raro es que desde una tablet si puedo conectarme, mi portatil es un Ubuntu 23.04, sin embargo me entere de este detalle, ojalá también te sirva.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ka0G3iIfZ9Y

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/400490)

Comment: en el video de youtube que anexe esta la posible solución, a mi me sirvió

Comment: Saludos @LuisAngelEscalanteLapouble, tu respuesta la consideré como comentario por el hecho de que no es completa, lo mejor en este caso habria sido que agregaras la respuesta escrita según al tutorial que propones y finalmente solo dejar el enlace como referencia, el problema es ¿Qué pasa si por alguna razón dan de baja el video? entonces tu respuesta quedaria inservible. ;)